# How to hide automatically iOS permission alerts on app launch?

Tags: ios, calabash, calabash-ios, ios-permissions

I'm writing UI tests for iOS using Calabash framework. Everything is fine, but system permission alerts are very annoying, because they disrupt test flow. Some time ago I read about open source library which grants required permissions automatically on iOS Simulator. Does anybody know its name or some other way to solve that problem?

Comment: isNot possible to do in the apple phone.

Answer (score 1):

Calabash iOS automatically dismisses most Privacy dialogs.  [wiki page](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/Managing-Privacy-Alerts%3A--Location-Services%2C-APNS%2C-Contacts)

We have a sample application that demonstrates that this behavior is working:

[Permissions](https://github.com/calabash/Permissions)

I down voted the (now deleted) other answer because these dialogs block UIAutomation so no gestures can be performed.

Comment: Yeah, I know that Calabash can dismiss permission alerts. But it will be much better to grant permissions automatically to avoid alerts at all.

Comment: On physical devices, it is not possible.  On iOS Simulators, it is possible.  https://github.com/calabash/run_loop/pull/391